# ImageButton in a custom ListView adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, custom-adapter

i have some problems with two image buttons in a custom `listView`. I'm not an android master, so I've followed some tutorial about custom adapter. What i want is a list of row, and in each row there are 1 text view, and 2 image buttons. Text view also must be clickable. This is what i want.

[image]

And this is the XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="239dp"
    android:layout_height="61dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" />


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/simpleImageButton"
    android:layout_width="62dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"

    tools:srcCompat="@drawable/download" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/simpleImageButton2"
    android:layout_width="62dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="68dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"

    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    tools:srcCompat="@drawable/audio" />
```

And this is the java class of the adapter:

```
public class LuogoListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Luogo> {
private static final String TAG = "LuogoListAdapter";
private Context mcontext;
int mresouce;
ImageButton posButton;
ImageButton audButton;
TextView nameLoc;

public LuogoListAdapter( Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Luogo> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    mcontext = context;
    mresouce = resource;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    String name = getItem(position).getNomeLuogo();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(mresouce, parent, false);
    TextView tvNome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tvNome.setText(name);
    posButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.simpleImageButton);
    posButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    audButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.simpleImageButton2);
    audButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    /*posButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
    ADD FUTURE ACTION
    audButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
    */
    return convertView;
}


}
```

But when i run the application i can't see my two Image Buttons:

[image]

Comment: Can you see the images in xml preview ?

Comment: I think you forgot the android:src="" attribute in your image buttons.

Comment: @tomerpacific, 
     `tools:srcCompat="@drawable/audio` should work for resource reference

Comment: @Farouk i can see the images in the xml design preview. Like in this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmKOV.png

Comment: Try to use: app: srcCompat="@drawable/download". if it still not work fine, maybe the problem is from your image file. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

in your layout file use `app:srcCompat="@drawable/audio"` instead of `tools:srcCompat="@drawable/audio"`. tools is used for visual representation in android studio but not on the actual device

Edit

So app:srcCompat works if you have set the following in your apps build.gradle file under 
`defaultConfig { vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true }`

Below is how i would implement my layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/simpleImageButton"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/simpleImageButton"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/simpleImageButton" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/simpleImageButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/simpleImageButton2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/simpleImageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/simpleImageButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

If you want the image button to not have the gray background then instead of app:srcCompat use android:background="@drawable/download"

Comment: I changed those locs but the image is not showed. See the picture https://imgur.com/a/14tR8Kf
Now the text is overwritten by the image button

Comment: well the text is overlaid because you set it to have a fixed width. adding a new answer that will take care of everything for you

Comment: Solved using the default image of android. I think that the problem is the png file that i used

Comment: oh great. kindly accept my answer as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

KIndly check the answer,Just copy and post the answer

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="239dp"
    android:layout_height="61dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/simpleImageButton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"        
    android:src="@drawable/download" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/simpleImageButton2"
    android:layout_width="62dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="68dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/audio" />
```